# Collision Detection on C++ using sprites and setObject

Tags: c++, sprite, collision-detection, game-boy-advance

I am trying to create a very basic endless runner gamer and i am stuck with collision detection's. I am programming for a GBA emulator using notepad++. The code below is my main game while loop. The sprites are 4x4 tiles and each tile is 8x8 pixels. Below the main loop is the code for gravity acting down on the sprite. 'setObject(0,...) is the character sprite setObject(1,...) is the platform sprite. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
while (true)
{
    const uint8_t currentKeys = REG_KEYINPUT; 

    if (frame % 4 == 0) //change player sprite every 4 frame
    {

        if (run != 14)      //when last sprite is reached reset to original values
        {
            run = run + 2; //change run to next sprite
        }
        else
        {
            run = 0;            
            frame = 0;
            score ++; //adding one to score variable everytime loop is entered      
        }
    }

    SetObject(0,
        ATTR0_SHAPE(2) | ATTR0_8BPP | ATTR0_REG | ATTR0_Y(80),  //calling from spritesheet Stickmen 
        ATTR1_SIZE(2) | ATTR1_X(108),
        ATTR2_ID8(run));                                        //calling sprite 

    SetObject(1,
        ATTR0_SHAPE(2) | ATTR0_8BPP | ATTR0_REG | ATTR0_Y(112),
        ATTR1_SIZE(2) | ATTR1_X(108),
        ATTR2_ID8(100));

    if (currentKeys != prevKeys)  
    {
        if ((currentKeys & KEY_UP) == 0)
        {
            jumpY = -6.0f;
        }
    }

    frame += 1;
    prevKeys = currentKeys;
    //DrawScore();
    Physics();
    WaitVSync();
    UpdateObjects();
}
return 0;
}

void Physics()
{
    playerY = playerY + jumpY; // setting player to PlayersY + the jumpY value attained by user
    jumpY = jumpY + gravity; // because jump is negative, adding gravity cause it to fall down the screen
    SetObjectY(0, playerY);     
}
```

Comment: Among a number of other things, you need `{ }` braces around your `else` case.

Comment: when i add in braces the sprite animation doesn't work, i havent been able to fix that yet, but its not my main concern.

Comment: @NiallClarke Indenting in C++ does nothing except make the code readable.  It does not affect how an `if()` statement works.  To perform multiple statements for an `else`, you have to create a block (`{ }`) and place those statements inside that block.

Comment: Well the fact that you tabbed in 3 lines implies that you think all of those will only execute in your `else` condition which is wrong. Only the `run = 0;` is inside the `else` block, the next two lines will execute every iteration.

Comment: Also you should use `if (frame % 4 == 0)` instead of trying to list every multiple of `4` that you can think of

Comment: I apologies it does work, but the animation runs the same way. That's not my main concern though, I'm trying to focus on collision detection before i make the program more efficient

Comment: You haven't really asked anything.

Comment: I am trying to detect collisions between my two sprites. Which are called in  setObject from a sprite sheet. I want to know how to find the X and Y position of each sprite through setObject.

Comment: Distance between 2 points = sqrt(x^2 + y^2), find the center of each of your objects, or better yet your surrounding rectangles, calculate that distance on a move and when that distance == 0, kaboom!

Comment: sorry, very embarrassing... dist = `sqrt( (x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2 )`